# How does Local storage work on domain levels? Two sites using same key to store data?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, keyvaluepair

I'm aware that local storage uses key  value pairs to store data, but what if two websites use the same key to store data? how do they not overwrite one another when data has been inputted?

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is bound to their origin. So there is an "own" local storage for every domain (and protocol).

Answer (score 0):

The local storage and the session storage are unique peer `protocol://host:port` so you can have keys with the same name on different domains.